# Keyboard with scrollView

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

There are numerous apps on google play having scrollView in softKeyboard.

> As android is open source, where can i find that keyboard which has scroll embed on emoji like given image. i think i want open source keyboard for Android 4.x.x

[image]

Or tell me how to add scroll to custom softKeyboard. I have tried many ways.

First i tried to add ScrollView to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.zeuxislo.emojikeyboard.EmojiKeyboardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground" >
        </com.zeuxislo.emojikeyboard.EmojiKeyboardView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wao what a keyBoard"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Also tried adding horizontalScrollView to qwerty.xml and other emoji.xml under xml folder**

Comment: You can use this lib: https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Comment: I know this library but it is for single app.I want to embed it for all system apps. I mean i want softkeyboard. Not specific app to app keyboard.

Comment: Basically, you want to take the source code for a keyboard app, but you don't want to build an app? What are you trying to do then ?

Comment: why orientation of `LinearLayout` is vertical when you want to scroll horizontal?

Comment: Rahul Tiwari it doesn't have any effect on setting it to linear or horizontal . All logic is to be implemented inside EmojiKeyBoardService

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're wanting to install a new keyboard on your device and then make that the default one. Try some like [Google's keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en), or just look around for others. Once you get it installed then go to Setting > Language & input > Current keyboard and then just select whichever one you prefer.

Comment: You're kidding right? I want to build one - and I wanted to know how I can achieve this - creating a keyboard with a scroll to see the keyboard items.

Comment: You say you want it to not be app specific, so you want it to build one that acts in the manner that I suggested? That you can install to your device?

Comment: Yes - that's what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for this :
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-6.0.0_r1/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/emoji/

Keyboard code

Latest/Marshmallow:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-6.0.0_r1

KitKat
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1

Comment: Something along the lines. Thanks for your response - it's the best one so far so I'll award the bounty to you!